# Splunk Cloud search query with variable does not return results

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a query that does not return results and shows no errors (the same with where and search command):

```
"ExtendedProperties.PrCode"="myProductName" 
| eval myversion="12.916"|  where "ExtendedProperties.ProductVersion"=myversion
```

The query without eval returns results:

```
"ExtendedProperties.PrCode"="myProductName" 
|  search "ExtendedProperties.ProductVersion"="12.916"
```

The product version last three digits are the month (September) and the day (16), my final goal is to extract them from the current date, using the now() function. This will remove the need to update the query every day.
Unfortunately this query is also not returning results:

```
"ExtendedProperties.PrCode"="myProductName" 
| eval month = ltrim(tostring(strftime(now(),"%m")),"0") 
| eval day = strftime(now(),"%d") 
| eval version="12." + month + day 
| where "ExtendedProperties.ProductVersion"=version
```

Here is some sample data:

```
{"Timestamp":"2020-12-14T14:37:00.2662745Z","Categories":["someCategoryString"],"Metadata":["someMetadataString"],"ExtendedProperties":{"MachineId":"SomeMachineId","ProductVersion":"12.916","PrCode":"MyProductName","ProductType":"1","Type":"ProductUsed","Source":"SomeSourceString","SessionId":"SomeGuid","TimeStamp":"2020-12-14T14:36:56.7086819Z","Environment":"SomeEnvironment"}}
```

This returns results:

```
|makeresults | eval _raw = "{\"Timestamp\":\"2020-12-14T14:37:00.2662745Z\",\"Categories\":[\"someCategoryString\"],\"Metadata\":[\"someMetadataString\"],\"ExtendedProperties\":{\"MachineId\":\"SomeMachineId\",\"ProductVersion\":\"12.1219\",\"PrCode\":\"MyProductName\",\"ProductType\":\"1\",\"Type\":\"ProductUsed\",\"Source\":\"SomeSourceString\",\"SessionId\":\"SomeGuid\",\"TimeStamp\":\"2020-12-14T14:36:56.7086819Z\",\"Environment\":\"SomeEnvironment\"}}", month = ltrim(tostring(strftime(now(),"%m")),"0"), day = strftime(now(),"%d"),version="12."+month+day|spath | search "ExtendedProperties.ProductVersion"="12.1219"
```

However, when I replace the string  "12.1219" with the version variable that has the same value (at the end of the search), there are no results found:

```
|makeresults | eval _raw = "{\"Timestamp\":\"2020-12-14T14:37:00.2662745Z\",\"Categories\":[\"someCategoryString\"],\"Metadata\":[\"someMetadataString\"],\"ExtendedProperties\":{\"MachineId\":\"SomeMachineId\",\"ProductVersion\":\"12.1219\",\"PrCode\":\"MyProductName\",\"ProductType\":\"1\",\"Type\":\"ProductUsed\",\"Source\":\"SomeSourceString\",\"SessionId\":\"SomeGuid\",\"TimeStamp\":\"2020-12-14T14:36:56.7086819Z\",\"Environment\":\"SomeEnvironment\"}}", month = ltrim(tostring(strftime(now(),"%m")),"0"), day = strftime(now(),"%d"),version="12."+month+day|spath | search "ExtendedProperties.ProductVersion"=version
```

The expected output is one record that contains the expected version (12.1219 for today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if the field is not extracted properly, the query can return no results. So with this query, the results are shown as expected:

```
|makeresults | eval _raw = "{\"Timestamp\":\"2020-12-14T14:37:00.2662745Z\",\"Categories\":[\"someCategoryString\"],\"Metadata\":[\"someMetadataString\"],\"ExtendedProperties\":{\"MachineId\":\"SomeMachineId\",\"ProductVersion\":\"12.1219\",\"PrCode\":\"MyProductName\",\"Environment\":\"SomeEnvironment\"}}", month = ltrim(tostring(strftime(now(),"%m")),"0"), day = strftime(now(),"%d"),version="12."+month+day | rex "ProductVersion[\\\":]*(?<ExtractedProductVersion>[^\\\":]*)" | where ExtractedProductVersion=version
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `eval` and `where` or `eval` and `search`

Put it in the initial search:

```
"ExtendedProperties.PrCode"="myProductName" "ExtendedProperties.ProductVersion"="12.916"
```

Make Splunk do your work for you - and let it do it in the most efficient manner possible :)

### EDIT reflecting question update:

Try something like this:

```
index=ndx "ExtendedProperties.PrCode"="myProductName" "ExtendedProperties.ProductVersion"="12.*"
| eval monthday=strftime(now(),"%m%d")
| where match("ExtendedProperties.ProductVersion",monthday)
```

First, don't use two `eval`s when one will do :)

Second, get to know the various functions and their arguments like [`strftime`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#strftime.28X.2CY.29) and [common time formats](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Commontimeformatvariables). Or [`match`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/ConditionalFunctions#match.28SUBJECT.2C_.22REGEX.22.29)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I want to achieve a more complex search and I cannot realize why this more basic one is not working. Maybe I do something wrong with variable declaration? Could you please tell me what would be the correct syntax if a variable is used?

Comment: @K.B. - what are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: I added the query that is my final goal in my question. I want to take the month and the day from the current date, and then pass it as a part of the product version variable so that I do not have to update the query every day.

Comment: Thank you for the information, unfortunately the suggested query also does not return results.

Comment: @K.B. - if this isn't working, *and* your search isn't working ... then I suspect you have missed something about the data ... because I can only go off what you've shared. Please share some sample data so that we can help you better :)